Installing docker and docker-compose on Amazon linux 2 with Ansible fails - manually succeeds
I have two ec2 instances with Amazon Linux 2 OS on them (amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.20240610.1-x86_64-gp2)
uname -a
Linux ip-172-31-24-106.eu-central-1.compute.internal 4.14.345-262.561.amzn2.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri May 31 18:15:42 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

On one of them I install docker and docker-compose manually like so:

# # # Install docker # # # 

sudo yum update -y 

sudo yum install docker 

sudo service docker start 

sudo usermod -a -G docker ec2-user

docker version

Client:
 Version:           20.10.25




# # # Install docker-compose # # # 

sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-Linux-x86_64 -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

docker-compose version

Docker Compose version v2.27.1

ls -l /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 63052874 Jun 17 16:54 /usr/local/bin/docker-compose



This way everything works.
However when I try to install docker and docker-compose via Ansible I get an error.
This is the playbook that I apply :
---
- name: Install python3, docker, docker-compose
  hosts: [docker_server] 
  become: yes
  gather_facts: False 
  tasks:
    - name: Install python3 and docker
      ansible.builtin.yum: 
        use_backend: yum3 
        name: 
          - docker
          - python3-pip
        update_cache: yes
        state: present
    - name: Install Docker Compose
      get_url:                              
        url: https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-Linux-x86_64 
        dest: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
        mode: '+x'
      register: docker_compose_result
    - debug: var=docker_compose_result
    - name: Start docker daemon
      ansible.builtin.systemd:
        name: docker
        state: started
    - name: Install docker python module 
      ansible.builtin.pip:
        name: 
          - docker
          - docker-compose   

- name: Add ec2-user to docker group
  hosts: [docker_server] 
  become: yes
  tasks: 
    - name: Add ec2-user to docker group
      ansible.builtin.user: 
        name: ec2-user
        groups: docker  
        append: yes
    - name: Reconnect to server session
      ansible.builtin.meta: reset_connection


- name: Start docker containers
  hosts: [docker_server] 
  vars_files:
    - project-vars
  tasks:
    - name: Copy docker compose
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        src: /home/tomas/gitlab/ansible-learn-nana/docker-compose.yaml
        dest: /home/ec2-user/docker-compose.yaml
    - name: Start container from compose
      community.docker.docker_compose_v2: 
        project_src: /home/ec2-user 


This is the error that I get :
PLAY [Install python3, docker, docker-compose] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Install python3 and docker] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [18.153.66.78]

TASK [Install Docker Compose] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [18.153.66.78]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [18.153.66.78] => {
    "docker_compose_result": {
        "changed": true,
        "checksum_dest": null,
        "checksum_src": "38ab1e3229c2627dd788d299e526145491aadd1d",
        "dest": "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose",
        "elapsed": 1,
        "failed": false,
        "gid": 0,
        "group": "root",
        "md5sum": "24120814a7df4f78aca2a31b17067e64",
        "mode": "0755",
        "msg": "OK (63052874 bytes)",
        "owner": "root",
        "size": 63052874,
        "src": "/home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1718643910.4494328-246157-215366873451751/tmp4m7jlk7a",
        "state": "file",
        "status_code": 200,
        "uid": 0,
        "url": "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-Linux-x86_64"
    }
}

TASK [Start docker daemon] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [18.153.66.78]

TASK [Install docker python module] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [18.153.66.78]

PLAY [Add ec2-user to docker group] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [18.153.66.78]

TASK [Add ec2-user to docker group] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [18.153.66.78]

TASK [Reconnect to server session] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************

PLAY [Start docker containers] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [18.153.66.78]

TASK [Copy docker compose] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [18.153.66.78]

TASK [Start container from compose] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [18.153.66.78]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Docker CLI /usr/bin/docker does not have the compose plugin installed"}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
18.153.66.78               : ok=9    changed=6    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   




When I ssh into this machine which is supposed to be configured by Ansible this is what I see :
cd /usr/local/bin/  # Directory where curl downloads docker-compose
ls -l
total 24
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 212 Jun 17 17:05 distro
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 215 Jun 17 17:05 docker-compose
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 212 Jun 17 17:05 dotenv
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 213 Jun 17 17:05 jsonschema
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 233 Jun 17 17:05 normalizer
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 216 Jun 17 17:05 wsdump



If I try to download docker-compose manually on this failed machine , the file size is different :
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-Linux-x86_64 -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

cd /usr/local/bin/ # Directory where curl downloads docker-compose
ls -l
total 61596
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      212 Jun 17 17:05 distro
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 63052874 Jun 17 17:08 docker-compose
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      212 Jun 17 17:05 dotenv
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      213 Jun 17 17:05 jsonschema
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      233 Jun 17 17:05 normalizer
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      216 Jun 17 17:05 wsdump



So it seems that my playbook fails at this task:
- name: Install Docker Compose
      get_url:                              
        url: https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-Linux-x86_64 
        dest: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
        mode: '+x'
      register: docker_compose_result
    - debug: var=docker_compose_result


Even though debug shows "status_code": 200
Any advice on where could I look at with be highly appreciated.

Hope you are having a great day. I faced the same issue.
The issue is that you are using community.docker.docker_compose_v2 with docker compose version 1.
I would like to say that I don't recommend you go back to community.docker.docker_compose as it is deprecated.
I am facing the same issue with Amazon Linux and I got could get around by two ways. not ideal but it is temporary:
1st work around:
    - name: Start containers from compose 
  ansible.builtin.command:
    cmd: docker-compose up -d

2nd work around:
      become: yes
  vars_files:
    - project-vars
  tasks:
    - name: Copy Docker compose
      copy: 
        src: /root/ansible/Ansible/docker-compose.yaml
        dest: /home/ec2-user  
    - name: Docker login
      docker_login:
        registry_url: https://index.docker.io/v1
        username: ibrahimosama
        password: "{{docker_password}}"
    - name: Start containers from compose 
      community.docker.docker_compose_v2:
        project_src: /home/ec2-user

The ultimate fix is to install docker compose version 2 instead:
    - name: Install docker compose V2 
  hosts: ec2
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Create directory for Docker CLI plugins
      file:
        path: /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins
        state: directory
        mode: '0755'
    - name: Download Docker Compose V2 binary
      get_url:
        url: https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.18.0/docker-compose-linux-x86_64
        dest: /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
        mode: '0755'
    - name: Make Docker Compose binary executable
      file:
        path: /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
        mode: '0755'
    - name: Verify Docker Compose installation
      command: docker compose version
      register: docker_compose_version
      ignore_errors: yes
    - name: Show Docker Compose version
      debug:
        msg: "{{ docker_compose_version.stdout }}"
      when: docker_compose_version.rc == 0

My full project is on  https://github.com/ibrahim-osama-amin/Ansible/blob/main/deploy-docker.yaml

Your ultimate fix answer helped me realize I didn't read the documentation closely enough to find the the alternative to using a package. Thank you!
Link to that doc: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/linux/
